# Implement file Drag&Drop with LWjGL

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt, lwjgl, kotlin

I would like to ask how can i implement file drag and drop with LWjGL. 
I am not quite good with AWT so i tried to search for some code examples and found out that i need to create `DropTarget` object and provide him a `DropTargetListener` implementation. I also not sure what i should use as Component, I found `Display.getParent()` method which gives us a Component but it's usually returns `null`. I have no idea what to do with my DropTarget object after that

My code (it doesn't seem to work because nothing is printed):

```
    import java.awt.dnd.*
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display

    ...

    var dropListener =  object : DropTargetListener{
        override fun drop(dtde: DropTargetDropEvent?) {
            println("drop()")
        }

        override fun dragExit(dte: DropTargetEvent?) {
            println("dragExit()")
        }

        override fun dropActionChanged(dtde: DropTargetDragEvent?) {
            println("dropActionChanged()")
        }

        override fun dragEnter(dtde: DropTargetDragEvent?) {
            println("dragEnter()")
        }

        override fun dragOver(dtde: DropTargetDragEvent?) {
            println("dragOver()")
        }
    }

    var dropTarget = DropTarget(Display.getParent(), DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, dropListener, true)
```

Comment: The following works well for me: https://gist.github.com/cy6erGn0m/ba1d95d708c9d6195010  
Perhaps something wrong with the component itself. What the display mounted on ?

Comment: Yes, it's works in Swing based application. But I am writing LWjGL (OpenGL wrapper for Java)  application and don't have access to JFrame